# Using TikZ on Linux (Lyx)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, lyx, linux

I've recently upgraded to Linux, and without MikTeX I really have no idea how to manage my packages.
What should I do in order to use TikZ on Lyx in Linux?

Edit: oh yeah, I forgot: Linux is Ubuntu 12.10, I installed Lyx from the repository and that's it.

Comment: It depends on your Linux and your TeX installation. Which Linux do you use, did you install TeX from Linux repositories or the original TeX Live?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `apt` make your life easier:

If you are new to Linux, I do not suggest installing `texlive` from their homepage. That process is very easy, but the problem is that whenever you install anything with `apt` that depends on a `texlive` package, it won't recognize that you already have `texlive` installed. I'm pretty sure that Ubuntu 12.10 comes with texlive 2012 in the repos so I would suggest installing it from apt. If you have a lot of space and don't want to deal with missing packages:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

But if you just want the basics you don't have to install all of that. You could just do:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

In summary, `apt` makes sure that all of the packages and programs on your computer play nice with each other. Installing manually introduces a new kid to the playground that doesn't necessarily play by the rules.

Finally, reconfigure `LyX` so that it is aware of your new toys:

Start `LyX` and go to Tools > Reconfigure

Comment: Installing it now, will let you know how it worked

Answer (score 2):

Try downloading `texlive` from their official homepage. It's a large ISO but once you get it, it installs easily and then you can use `tlmgr` for package management. It's quite similar to miktex.

It comes with all the CTAN packages so you don't really need to install anything else  at the start.

Edit:

Oh, and specifically for TikZ, you should try getting KTikZ. It's very useful for creating figures as it shows updates in (almost) real-time.